# Swing,Java. Текст в поле, сравнение введенных текстов

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте, проблема такая- нужно написать в первом поле текст `"Собака кот лошадь"` во втором такой `"кот"` .При нажатии кнопки он должен проверить, есть ли "кот" в первом поле.
Написал такой код. Но он не запускает окошко приложения, а предлагает в консоли для Scanner произвести ввод и всё.
**Так как мне сделать сравнение двух текстов? Помогите пожалуйста**

```
public class Reader extends JFrame{
JButton b1, b2;
JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4;
JTextField t1, t2;
int i, k;
String a, b;
eHandler handler = new eHandler();
public Object m;

public Reader(String s){
    super(s);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    b1 = new JButton("Очистить");
    b2 = new JButton("Найти");
    l1 = new JLabel("Введите текст:");
    l2 = new JLabel("Введите нужное слово:");
    l3 = new JLabel("");
    l4 = new JLabel("");
    t1 = new JTextField(10);
    t2 = new JTextField(10);

    add(l1);
    add(t1);
    add(l2);
    add(t2);
    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    add(l3);
    add(l4);
    b2.addActionListener(handler);
    b1.addActionListener(handler);
}

public class eHandler implements ActionListener{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource()==b2){
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                String s = scan.nextLine();
                s = t1.getText();

                Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                String m = scan1.nextLine();
                m = t2.getText();

                 boolean checkContains1=s.contains(m);
                    b = "Ваше слово тут есть " + m;           
                s=t1.getText();
                l3.setText("check contains string 1 :"+checkContains1 );
                if (checkContains1==true){
                    m=t2.getText();
                }

            if(e.getSource()==b1){
                t1.setText(null);
                t2.setText(null);
                l3.setText("");
                l4.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну так вы так и велели делать. Предоставьте лучше минимальный компилируемый код, который демонстрирует работу GUI.

Comment: хорошо, сейчас сделаю

Comment: @LEQADA я добавил полный код, без подключения библиотек

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(e.getSource()==b2){


            String s = t1.getText();
       String m = t2.getText();
       boolean checkContains1=s.contains(m);

        b = "Ваше слово тут есть " + m; 
        s=t1.getText();
        l3.setText("check contains string 1 :"+checkContains1 );
       if (checkContains1) {
          m=t2.getText();

       }
```

ну вот никаких вроде консолей)

Comment: Перечитайте вопрос.

Comment: Так как мне сделать сравнение двух текстов? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А вы прочитайте весь вопрос, а не только то, что выделено жирным.

Comment: Не торопитесь. Удалите ответ, хорошенько ознакомьтесь с вопросом, отредактируйте свой ответ и верните обратно.

Comment: Вопрос же заключается в том что человеку надо узнать содержит ли строка1 строку2? в строке1 через пробел имеются имена ,а в строке2 только одно имя

Comment: Нет! ТС негодует из-за того, что программа работает не с GUI, а цитирую "предлагает в консоли для Scanner произвести ввод и всё".

Comment: а,извините,сейчас попробую дать нормальный ответ.

Comment: @L423R Так, у меня сейчас запустилось и вроде как должно работать. Наживаю "найти" и программа виснет.

Comment: А стоп, блиииин. Она типа работает, но только если я нажимаю "Найти" и начинаю все вбивать в консоли... Всё тлен.

Comment: секундочку,я просто работаю в netbeans,там все автоматически создается,сейчас ваш код допишу

Comment: @L423R там проще работать?)

Comment: Да конечно,там и конструктор есть)

Comment: так вроде я изменил код,но я не понимаю зачем вам так много переменных

Comment: Я сначала работал с цифрами, а потом нам дали программу со словами @L423R Поэтому я пытался изменить, еще не убрал.

Comment: Посмотрите ответ,у меня он нормально работает)

Comment: @L423R ААА, спасибо большое))
сейчас еще не много разберусь,нужно добавить тут. Если будут еще вопросы могу у вас спросить?

Comment: Да,конечно,чем смогу ,тем помогу)